# Execution environment variables Iw and Ie

Tags: evm, yellow-paper, message

According to the yellow paper, one of the Execution Environment variables is:

> Iw, the permission to make modifications to the
>   state.

I can't find further information about it, for example how it's set and what values it can get (I guess 1 or 0)

---

Also I'd like to make sure that the variable

> Ie, the depth of the present message-call or
>   contract-creation (i.e. the number of CALLs or
>   CREATEs being executed at present).

is only decremented by one for each CALL and CREATE opcodes, but never for a DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is based on the [current version of the yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf).

### I_w

> Iw, the permission to make modifications to the state

The importance of this flag is explained in the paragraph about Exceptional Halting:

[image]

Take into consideration only the last condition, it says that if the permission to modify is false and the current instruction is one specified by `W` (i.e., the instructions that may alter the state) then we have an exception.
For completeness I report also the function `W`:

[image]

I_w is normally set to `T` (true) and is set to `F` only when a STATICCALL is performed.

---

> is only decremented by one for each CALL and CREATE opcodes, but never for a DELEGATECALL or CALLCODE

This is wrong. Also DELEGATECALL and CALLCODE increment and decrement the callstack (it is specified in the yellow paper).